# Returning value after adding to database Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a firebase function in order to generate a 2 factor authentication OTP, I am adding secret to database and then returning to generate a QRCode to be able to work with an authenticator, however I can only return the secret and would like to confirm it is added to database before displaying, at the moment it returns regardless but sometimes nothing is in the database.

```js
exports.TOTPSetup = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

var speakeasy = require('speakeasy');
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({length: 20});
admin.firestore().collection('TOTPSecret').doc(data.uid).set({
secret:secret.base32
 },
     {merge:true});
if(context.auth.token.admin){
return secret;
}
});
```

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

`.set` returns a promise, so you have to return in the `.then` to ensure it was written successfully.

```js
exports.TOTPSetup = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

var speakeasy = require('speakeasy');
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({length: 20});
admin.firestore().collection('TOTPSecret').doc(data.uid)
  .set({ secret:secret.base32 }, {merge:true})
  .then(() => {
    // successfully written
    if(context.auth.token.admin){
      return secret;
    }
  })
  .catch(err => { // not successful });
});
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document